# Move a row to the bottom in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the SQL statement below:

```
SELECT
    row1 AS row1str,
    SUM(row2),
    SUM(row3),
    SUM(row4)
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    row1
UNION
SELECT
    'Total',
    SUM(row2),
    SUM(row3),
    SUM(row4),
FROM
    table1
ORDER BY
    CASE row1 WHEN 'Total' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, row1;
```

Which returns the sum of the unique values in each row, including an additional row which contains the sum of the values of each column. I added an ORDER BY clause as row1 contains words that begin with the letter 'u' and later.

The problem now is I am unable to move the 'Total' row to the bottom my results as running the query gives me this error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement
>   contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

This makes sense to me, as my 2nd SELECT statement does not contain row1 (I'm not sure whether my understanding of this error is 100% correct). However moving the ORDER BY clause to the first SELECT statement will surely return the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

I also tried giving row1 an alias and tried referring to that, but to no success.

So my question is, how can I move a row containing the value 'Total' to the bottom of my SQL query result?

Comment: one simple way would be to just add an extra column with `0` for your first query and `1` for your second query then order by that column. the error is raised on your case expression, not on `row1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Temp table,First insert sum values and finally insert total.

 CREATE TABLE #table1(row1 INT,row2 INT,row3 INT,row4 INT)

 INSERT INTO #table1(row1 ,row2 ,row3 ,row4)
 SELECT row1 AS row1str,SUM(row2),SUM(row3),SUM(row4)
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY row1

 INSERT INTO #table1(row1 ,row2 ,row3 ,row4)
 SELECT 'Total',SUM(row2),SUM(row3),SUM(row4),
 FROM table1

 SELECT * FROM #table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below and see.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT row1 AS row1str,
    SUM(row2),
    SUM(row3),
    SUM(row4)
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY row1
  UNION
  SELECT 'Total',
  SUM(row2),
  SUM(row3),
  SUM(row4)
  FROM table1
  )
ORDER BY row1str DESC;
```